# How Java String Pool Working?

Tags: java, string, string-pool

I am learning string implementations in java, got the following doubt while learning

```
String s1 = "name1";
String s2 = "name1"; // both strings having same value;
```

I know that,

```
s1==s2
```

above comparison will return false (based on what i studied, == compares the memory location of the string objects).

but this returns  true;

1. I want to know the reason why its returning 'true'?
2. Also how the memory will be allocated for a string literal in string pool(what really happens inside the string pool/back end);

for the following operations,

```
String s1 = "String1";
String s2 = s1+"xyz";
String s3 = s1.replace("i","o");
```

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: I have mistakenly put s2="name2" instead of "name1"; 
could you tell me what will be the result for other code snippets.

Comment: Why don't you just try to run it and see?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: I tried it, but what i want to know is how the string literals will be added into string pool. 
 1. whether s2 creates a new string with "String1xyz" or will it create "xyz" and point to s1&"xyz";
 2. similarly will s3 create new string "Strong1" in string pool?
I got the output but want to know the logic? or is there any way to check the string literals inside string pool?

Comment: Do a search of this site or on Google. So much has been written about this.